# regarding web parts & webpage design in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have seen many site where individual web parts load with busy icon when page loads. without using web parts how can develop a page where individual section will load with busy icon when page loads. please guide me with concept & code inas asp.net.

Comment: @Lazarus: And another word: JQuery !

Comment: @Quandary: And Jquery achieves it through... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Web Forms and not ASP.NET MVC. The easiest solution is to use the [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) class and add an [UpdateProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398821.aspx) control to show a spinner while updating.

1. Start by coding your web page as you normally would.
2. Add a ScriptManager control to your web page.
3. Add an UpdatePanel around the part of the page that should load asynchroneously. If the button that triggers the update is also located inside the panel, then you're done - you've got a web page that uses AJAX for updating.
4. If the control is located outside of the UpdatePanel you will need to look at the [AsyncPostBackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx).
5. Add an UpdateProgress control to show a spinner.

Note that UpdatePanels are ASP.NET Web From's automagic way of doing AJAX. There is a lot of JavaScript behind the scenes and the partial postbacks that your updates generate will run through most of a full page life cycle, and this can be a severe performance bottleneck.

Update: UpdatePanels are not suggested if you want the spinners to appear on the first load of the page. It could probably be done, but they would make the total load time for the page much slower.

I would take a look at some of the popular articles on Encorsia. You can start with this one: http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/.

Comment: your trick will work when partial post back will occur. in my case i want that when page will load first time then all the individual section will load and spinner will show for each section. i hope i am clear.